# Subir un excel en mi vista para mostrarlo en el controlador

Tags: php, javascript, array

Quiero...
Subir un archivo excel a mi servidor en mi vista (solo temporal porque solo lo leere, obtendre sus datos y los guardare a una DB), para luego usar fopen() en mi controlador, y abrir ese archivo que subio el user en la vista. (Estoy usando CI)

Problema...
Cuando trato de abrir el archivo en mi controlor pues no existe.

Lo que tengo...

**view**

```
<?php 
    print_r($_FILES);
    $archivo = fopen($_FILES["csv"]["tmp_name"], 'r');
?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('',array('id' => 'envio', 'role'=>'form')); ?>
    <legend>Importar Datos</legend>
    <?php if (isset($alerta) && $alerta): ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <?=$alerta ?>
        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Archivo CSV</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="csv" name="csv" placeholder="Archivo CSV">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="has_header" checked>
            El archivo contiene cabeceras
        </label>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="1">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function al_inicio()
    {
        console.log("on submit set");
        $( '#envio-t' )
        .submit( function( e ) {
            console.log('submitting');
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax( {
                // url: 'http://host.com/action/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: new FormData( this ),
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                dataType: 'script'
            } );
        } );
    }

</script>
```

**Controller_api**

```
    function dev_get(){
        print_r($_FILES);
        $archivo = fopen($_FILES["csv"]["tmp_name"], 'r');
    }
```

**Images**

[Vista](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnhyM.png)

[Controlador](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGHbI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Intenta de esta forma, siento que estas usando mal el fopen, ya que lo único que quieres son los datos.

```
$tmpName = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];
$csvAsArray = array_map('str_getcsv', file($tmpName));
```

Comment: O sea yo puedo leer los datos y mostrarlos ahi mismo en mi vista, pero lo que quiero es que ese archivo se refleje en mi controlador cuando el usuario suba el csv en la vista

Comment: tu vista y tu controlador, supongo, son dos archivos diferentes?

Comment: Si, por eso digo que uso CI como framework